# Sencha Touch - Map.Geo = null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sencha-touch

I am trying to follow this simple tutorial on Sencha Touch http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html

I keep getting the JavaScript error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null

This relates to the Map.geo property which is not getting set correctly. I am using the eact same code as on the link. I have tried putting on another box, in case it was a firewall issue, but get the same error.

Comment: Found the answer to this. Turns out that the tutorial is somewhat out of date compared to the latest source code. The following should work:

Instead of getLocation:true in your javascript file, replace it with
useCurrentLocation:true

Comment: Have some +rep as I was stuck on this too :)

Comment: You definitely deserve some rep on that one. Was banging my head just now on it.

Comment: I've actually found this to be a problem with Sencha in general.  A lot of their tutorials and documentation is out of date with the current version.  Oftentimes, finding what you're looking for is a huge mess.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

In your Application JavaScript File, replace `getLocation:true` with `useCurrentLocation:true`.

Comment: @ptamzz are you Adrian Westlake? If so, please ask your accounts to be merged then you can Accept this answer.

Comment: No. I'm not Adrian. I'd the same problem and this fixed it.